# OLD DLL is picking after deploying the dll into Bin folder in server

Tags: asp.net, dll

After publishing the asp.net site into local folder then copied the dll into server bin folder.

*Here after publishing the site dynamic dll's are generating.(App_Web_xxxx)

I have copied the dynamic dll to server.But still it is picking old dll,if i remove the old dll error is throwing as Could not load the assembly "App_Web_xxx"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bTxC.png)

Comment: Sorry, but I'm having trouble understanding this question. Maybe try rewriting it. Maybe try describing your setups separately. There seem to be at least three setups: on the server, copied to local, modified local by swapping the dll.

Comment: I have done changes in one of the code file AdminEmpoyee.aspx.cs after building the solution and deployed the website in local system ,then generated dynamic dll for the project . Server:-- Took the dynamic dll and paste it in server bin folder ,however it is taking old dll instead of new dll.(hence my code changes are not working).if i remove the old dll,error is throwing as . Error:Could not load the assembly App_Web_xxxx